# Django Not Found: /media/ , GET /media/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2679

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am currently building a project which i have to use media. Since i have used media before i copy pasted everyting from my other project and altough the original is working my current project is not. I can upload and select fotos thru admin page but it does not show up in html

My view:

```
def index(request):

    dergi = Dergi.objects.all()
    kitap = Kitap.objects.all()
    yazar = Yazar.objects.all()
    siir = Siir.objects.all()

    template = loader.get_template("index.html")
    context={
        "DERGI":dergi,
        "KITAP":kitap,
        "YAZAR":yazar,
        "SIIR":siir,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

My model:

```
class Kitap(models.Model):
    isim = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    yazar = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to="foto", null=True)
```

My url:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path("", include("index.urls"))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And my html:

```
<img src="/media/{{ KITAP.foto }}" alt="" class="rounded-t-lg">
<img src="/media/{{ KITAP.foto.url }}" alt="" class="rounded-t-lg">
<img src="{{ KITAP.foto.url }}" alt="" class="rounded-t-lg">
```

i have tried all but it just gives me error:
GET /media/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2679 or:
Not Found: /foto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your **index** view function **KITAP** is a queryset not a single query. try for loop in template or send a single object from view using **Kitap.objects.get(pk=some_value)** method or something like **KITAP[0]** or **get_object_or_404(id=some_value)**.

For loop in template will be like this:

```
{% for obj in KITAP %}
    <img src="{{ obj.foto.url }}" alt="" class="rounded-t-lg">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are sending all the instances of `Kitap` model using `.all()` method, so you should iterate over all the instances, like so:

```html
{% for ki in KITAP %}
    <img src="{{ ki.foto.url }}" alt="" class="rounded-t-lg">
{% endfor %}
```